# Use bluetooth headset remote as A/V controller

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, microphone

I recently got a pair of Bluetooth headphones with an in-line remote. After updating drivers I was able to get the headphones and microphone working with my computer. During the driver installation process one of the items listed was an a/v remote which got me thinking... is it possible to use the remote buttons as a remote to control operations on my computer (i.e., Powerpoint)?

I am using Windows 7; the remote has volume + and - and a play/pause button. As far as interaction goes, it seems like when I'm connected to the computer the volume is localized to the headphones because there are no changes on the desktop controls.